# printing output of command history 1 from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, history

Here's my problem, from console if I type the below,

```
var=`history 1`
echo $var
```

I get the desired output. But when I do the same inside a shell script, it is not showing any output. Also, for other commands like `pwd`, `ls` etc, the script shows the desired output without any issue.

Comment: var=`history 1` i.e. backquotehistorybackquote

Comment: I assume that `history` command only works in an interactive shell.

Comment: Replace `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/bash -i`.

Comment: output is shown but the output is not as expected....i.e. does not show the last command entered.

Comment: Do you want the `history` from the *parent* process, that is the interactive session that launched this script?

Answer (score 0):

As value of variable contains space, add quotes around it.

E.g.:

```
var='history 1'
echo $var
```

Comment: i want the output of the below to printed from a shell script
#history 1

Comment: you can copy paste this code to your shell script and it will work.

Comment: #./test.sh output is --> history 3 #cat test.sh #!/bin/bash var='history 3' echo $var EXPECTED is the below, # history 3 404 2018-02-19 12:16:08 ./test.sh 405 2018-02-19 12:16:10 cat test.sh 406 2018-02-19 12:16:14 history 3

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is this as follows:

1- Ask user for the number till which user need to print the `history` in script.

2- Run the script and take Input from user and get the output as follows:

```
cat get_history.ksh
echo "Enter the line number of history which you want to get.."
read number

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
then
        echo "Usage of script: get_history.ksh number_of_lines"
        exit
else
        history "$number"
fi
```

Added logic where it will check arguments if number of arguments passed is 0 then it will exit from script then.

Answer (score 0):

By default `history` is turned off in a script, therefore you need to turn it on:

```
set -o history
var=$(history 1)
echo "$var"
```

Note the preferred use of `$( )` rather than the deprecated backticks.

However, this will only look at the history of the current process, that is this shell script, so it is fairly useless.