# Bash - current_history doesnt execute

Tags: linux, bash, history

im trying to call the following within a bash script:

```
`history -a current_history`
```

it is supposed to create the file with the commands executed this session.

Works perfectly fine in a shell enviroment

Does not work within a bash script

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: See: [How can I use history command in a bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/546556/336375) and [printing output of command history 1 from shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48860590/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus Okay, i apreciate the link you sent but this doesnt work when using history -a

Comment: You will only get the commands that you have used in your script. Remove both backticks. Otherwise you have to use this: `. ./script.sh`

Comment: Removing back ticks makes no difference, the file is still not being created. The only point in which a file gets created is using the link you provided's method but this then cannot be used with -a to provide current session results